# How to set up an OpenVPN Access Server inside of NetworkManager for GNOME?

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, gnome, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on a VPS I rent out from Atlanta. It is running CentOS 7 and is using the latest version of the OpenVPN Access Server software.

I want to set up my VPN inside of the NetworkManager GUI provided in GNOME (Fedora 21). However, I do not know where to retrieve the needed information (nor do I know what the needed information *is*) to successfully get it working inside of GNOME.

Currently, I connect to my VPN by opening a terminal and running `sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/myvpnclient.ovpn`. I would like to use it inside of the GNOME interface as shown here.

[image: The GNOME NetworkManager interface for OpenVPN]

Is my gateway the VPN address, such as **vpn.example.com**? What type of authentication does a default OpenVPN server require? I know in my configuration file, there are multiple keys that seem to be embedded in the file itself.

If the authentication is username + certificates (which I believe it is), where can I find my user certificate, CA certificate, and private key? Are those located somewhere on the server or do I need to generate those locally on this machine?

Thank you.